# Breaking chocolate problem and Euler characteristic.

Tags: general-topology, graph-theory, planar-graphs

There is the following Problem:

> Given an $m \times n$ chocolate bar, where you can only break it along the gridlines and only break one piece at the time. What is the minimum amout of steps needed to break it into $1\times1$ pieces?

> Answer: You always need $m \times n -1$ Steps.

Now, my gut is telling me that this is related to the Euler characteristic. If that is the case, where can i find more information as to why/how that is the case?

P.S. This is not a homework problem, just a question about the more general principles and ways of seeing it.

Comment: Figure out the answer for a $2 \times3$ piece and then a $3 \times 4$ piece.

Comment: I proved the answer without the Euler char. But my question is specificaly related to it. (This is not a homework problem, just a question about the more general principles.

Comment: do you know the interpretation of Euler Characteristic in terms of homology (esp of simplicial complexes, with $\mathbb F_2$ coefficients)?

Comment: Same problem [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2897007/305862).

Comment: @user8675309 I'll say no. Because i never really took the time to understand them. But i have the required knowledge in order to be able to understand.

Comment: Each piece is contractible, so the chocolate bar $X$ has $\chi(X) = \dim H_0(X, \mathbb{Q}) = \#\{\text{pieces the bar has been broken into}\}$ at each point in the process. But that's really just an overcomplicated way of saying that the piece count increases by $1$ at each step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like your thought, there is indeed a (very simple) Euler characteristic description, although I think it turns out to be a little disappointing because it's really not much different than the "square counting" solution that is linked in the comments.

But here goes anyway.

From the assumption given, each "break" is carried out on a single piece, breaking that piece along a "fault line" which follows the grid. Let's examine how the numbers of faces, edges, and vertices change from "before" the break to "after" the break.

The number of faces is the the same before and after the break (namely $m \times n$).

Before the break, assume that the fault line has $k$ edges, it therefore also has $k+1$ vertices. After the break, each of those $k$ edges and $k+1$ vertices along the fault line has doubled, producing $2k$ edges and $2k+2$ vertices.

The numbers of vertices and edges *not* along the fault line is the same before and after the break.

The net change in the Euler characteristic is therefore
\begin{align*}
\chi_{\text{after}} - \chi_{\text{before}} &= (\text{vertices after} - \text{vertices before}) - (\text{edges after} - \text{edges before}) \\
  &= ((2k+2)-(k+1)) - (2k - k) \\
  &= 1
\end{align*}
That is to say: after each break, the Euler characteristic has increased by $1$. Since the Euler characteristic started at $1$ and ended at $m \times n$, there are $m \times n - 1$ breaks.

Comment: Since this is the best you found, but you were disappointed. May I ask what thought/(direction you mind pointed towards) made my thought interesting?

Comment: It is interesting to me that my intuition was pointing towards some quantities being preserved, whereas you did the exact opposite. I guess my intuition went along the lines of: the number of steps is constant since the Characteristic of the pieces remained unchanged at all times. I am writing as i am thinking, but to illustrate the thought, the number of steps needed to cut an annulus into n-annuluses is invariant.

Comment: Interesting because I like little Euler characteristic arguments!

Comment: Cutting along circles does preserve Euler characteristic, as your comment suggests. However, what you cut along matters. Cutting along arcs increases Euler characteristic by $1$, as my argument shows.

Comment: Yes, but it is not what I meant with my comment. I meant that the new piece that is created by breaking has the same caracteristic as the piece from which it was created. But it seems that i am kind of moving away from the original question and more towards asking wether or not/under what circumstances you can cover something with stuff of another characteristic.